# Working with jquery.validationEngine and codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, jquery-validation-engine

I am trying to make a form which would check if an username is available or not. I started to use jquery.validationEngine ([link](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/)) because it looks extremely simple. However, since I'm using codeigniter, I have a problem with that validation... Example on the mentioned site looks like:

```
$("#formID").validationEngine({
 ajaxSubmit: true,
  ajaxSubmitFile: "ajaxSubmit.php",
  ajaxSubmitMessage: "Thank you, we received your inscription!",
                ajaxSubmitExtraData: "securityCode=38709238423&name=john",
 success :  false,
 failure : function() {}
})
```

What I need is to change `ajaxSubmitFile: "ajaxSubmit.php",` line to match my codeigniter's MVC pattern, so I tried something like

```
ajaxSubmitFile: "<?php echo site_url('register/check_user'); ?>",
```

where `register` is my controller and `check_user` is a function within that controller. No matter what I try here I get 404 error in validationEngine debugger.

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found an answer...
I was editing wrong file all the time... I was supposed to edit `jquery.validationEngine-en.js`... There is a line which points to validation file... After editing that line, I could see `$_POST` data in my controller...